# Seeedstudio Wifi shield v1.1 Not working with Arduino Mega 2560

Tags: wifi

I have been trying use the [Seeedstudio wifi shield v1.1](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/Wifi-Shield-p-1220.html) with Arduino Mega 2560 as part of my project but I could not make the WiFly library provided on the [wiki](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Wifi_Shield_V1.1) work with the Mega. I tried to run the example sketch wifly_test but it did not work I tried some troubleshooting and found that the write commands to the shield were not successful. After a few hours of searching on the internet, I found out the problem and was able to solve it. I am posting my solution below. Anyone is welcome to add to my solution.

Comment: Sooo, there's no question then? If you can find the answer on the internet and already did, I fail to see why you would post this on here.

Comment: I figured the problem as a result of my search and not the solution. Please refer to my solution below

Answer (score 1):

The WiFly library provided at the Seeedstudio wiki uses the software serial to communicate with the WiFi shield. All the example files provided by the WiFly library use pins 2 and 3 as the Rx and Tx of the software serial. Moreover, the Wifi shield only allows pins 0-7 to be chosen as Rx and Tx by using different jumper combinations.
The [SoftwareSerial](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/softwareSerial) library, on the other hand, has the following limitation for the Arduino Mega

> Not all pins on the Mega and Mega 2560 support change interrupts, so only the following can be used for RX: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 50, 51, 52, 53, A8 (62), A9 (63), A10 (64), A11 (65), A12 (66), A13 (67), A14 (68), A15 (69).

Thus, as a workaround, I jumped pin 2 of the shiled with pin 10 (Rx of Software Serial) and pin 3 with pin 11 (Tx of Software Serial) using connecting wires and used the jumper setting given on the wiki. Finally I made the following changes in the example code

```
// Pins' connection
// Arduino       WiFly
//  10    <---->    TX (via connecting pin 2 to 10 on wifi shield)
//  11    <---->    RX (via connecting pin 3 to 11 on wifi shield)
```

```cpp
SoftwareSerial uart(10, 11); //change software serial pins for Mega
```

This allowed the Mega to communicate with the Wifi shield successfully using the WiFly library.